# javascript- how to prevent alert two times?

Tags: javascript

I have a unique situation, my page looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I can choose to copy one link or copy multiple link based on the checkbox I selected. I have two functions,one for `Copy` button and another one for `Copy selected URL`,where this function calls the first function.

```
// multiple copy
  function copymultiplelink() {

                    var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                    if(selectedFiles.length < 1 ){
                        alert("Please select at least one file.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var filesList = [];
                    var $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                    $fileChecks.each(function() {
                        filesList.push($(this).val());
                    });

                    alert("You have copied " + filesList.length+ " URL");
                    copyURL(filesList);

                }


// single copy

   function copyURL(url) {
            var copyText = url;
            var el = document.createElement('textarea');
            el.value = copyText;
            el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
            el.style = {
                position: 'absolute',
                left: '-9999px'
            };
            document.body.appendChild(el);
            el.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
            document.body.removeChild(el);
            alert("You have copied the URL");
        }
```

So,it's much easier for me to call the second function but when I click the Copy multiple button,I will receive two alerts,one from each function.

Is there a way that I can only show:

```
alert("You have copied " + filesList.length+ " URL");
```

when I select the `copy selected url` button?

At the same time,I too need to call `copyURL()` to copy all my selected URL.

Comment: You could move the alert outside the function, eg:

button_click(function{ copyurl(); alert("blah");});

Comment: I don't follow what you mean

Comment: Better to prevent alerts even one time. They are annoying.

Comment: `alert` is good to debug but there are even better option than `alert`. 
`console.log` does a better job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand you well. You don't want to show alert when it was already shown by `copymultiplelink()`. Then maybe call `copyURL(url)` with a flag that tells `copyURL(url)` to show or not to show msg.

```
function copyURL(url, showMsg) {

  // your code

  if (showMsg === true) {
    alert("You have copied the URL");
  }

}
```

and then inside `copymultiplelink()` tell it to not show message

```
copyURL(filesList, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do Like this:

```
// multiple copy
function copymultiplelink() {

                var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                if(selectedFiles.length < 1 ){
                    alert("Please select at least one file.");
                    return false;
                }
                var filesList = [];
                var $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                $fileChecks.each(function() {
                    filesList.push($(this).val());
                });

                alert("You have copied " + filesList.length+ " URL");
                copyURL(filesList, false);

            }


// single copy

function copyURL(url, isAlertNeeded=true) {
        var copyText = url;
        var el = document.createElement('textarea');
        el.value = copyText;
        el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
        el.style = {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: '-9999px'
        };
        document.body.appendChild(el);
        el.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        document.body.removeChild(el);
        isAlertNeeded && alert("You have copied the URL");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a parameter to `copyUrl(url, showAlert)` and then `copymultiplelink` can call `copyUrl`with showAlert to false while your buttons call it with showAlert to true.

Don't forget to display alert based on showAlert value in copyUrl function :)

Code:

```
// multiple copy
  function copymultiplelink() {

                    var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                    if(selectedFiles.length < 1 ){
                        alert("Please select at least one file.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var filesList = [];
                    var $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
                    $fileChecks.each(function() {
                        filesList.push($(this).val());
                    });

                    alert("You have copied " + filesList.length+ " URL");
                    copyURL(filesList, false); // false to not show alert

                }


// single copy

   function copyURL(url, showAlert) {
            var copyText = url;
            var el = document.createElement('textarea');
            el.value = copyText;
            el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
            el.style = {
                position: 'absolute',
                left: '-9999px'
            };
            document.body.appendChild(el);
            el.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
            document.body.removeChild(el);
            if (showAlert) {
               alert("You have copied the URL");
            }
        }
```